# MySQL Now() between two Date Time Time Zone

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table for `coupons`.
Each coupon has `start date time` `and end date time`.
My timezone is +30:00

**At 09:16 PM** (21:16 according to my datetype), I run this query;

```
SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE NOW() BETWEEN coupon_date_start AND coupon_date_end
```

**And I got this result;**

[image]

The result at the bottom should be expired and not appear. That item's end time was 09:14 PM and I run this at 09:16 PM.

Any idea how can I fix this? (I also set my timezone for that table)

My table schema;
[image]

**I fixed by setting my timezone as +3 UTC in mysql and I also changed datetime to timestamp of columns.**

Comment: Could `NOW()` be different for the DB to what method you are using to determine the current time?

Comment: @James What exactly did you mean? I want coupon be expired, if its end time out of current time.

Comment: You say that `NOW()` is "09:16", but do you know that is correct - e.g. what if `NOW()` in your database is a different time zone to wherever you are getting your time from? or 3 mins slower, or a day, etc

Comment: In fact, I got result if I make it other day. It's not working about times. However, I set my time zone for table and also set time zone while creating that coupon.

Comment: In mysql (PHPMyAdmin, Workbench or command line) what does this return `SELECT NOW();`

Comment: Day is true but clock is wrong. Where can I fix? 11:47:18

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173274/discussion-between-keremoflu4-and-james).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your MySQL timezone, you can use `CONVERT_TZ` function

```
SELECT * 
FROM coupons 
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','+03:00') BETWEEN coupon_date_start AND coupon_date_end
```

[CONVERT_TZ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0578e/1

Comment: This is just an example I would like to express that can use `CONVERT_TZ ` function

Comment: I run this, still get that 'should expired' item. Do you think I had problem about clock types like 09:00 PM is 21:00 also?

Comment: The link that you sent me worked correct. What do you think I could missed?

Comment: I created start and end time as datetime

Comment: @keremoflu4 Is your  Date Time of  Db computer correct?

Comment: Thanks all, Yes time was wrong. I set time zone again of database now it works. I also set datetime to timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM coupons 
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),'+00:00','+03:00') BETWEEN coupon_date_start AND coupon_date_end
CONVERT_TZ
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0578e/1

Comment: some explanation would make the answer better